# bash recursive xtrace

Tags: bash

Is there any way to run bash script X so that if X call executable bash script Y then Y starts by 'sh -eux'?

X.sh:

```
./Y.sh
```

Y.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo OK
```

Comment: Why not `#!/bin/sh -eux` in `Y.sh`?

Comment: And if sometimes you must run Y.sh without this, create a wrapper for Y.sh that invokes it this way and always use the wrapper in X.sh.

Comment: Modifications of X and Y aren't possible, because they aren't mine

Comment: how much control do you have over the environment? are you root? can you rename the scripts? can you change the PATH environment variable?

Comment: i'm not root and can't rename Y. i think 'export PATH' is always allowed

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is possible to make a subshell run using the same shell options set in the parent by exporting the `SHELLOPTS` environment variable.

In your case where `X.sh` and `Y.sh` cannot be edited, I'd create a wrapper script that simply exports `SHELLOPTS` before calling `X.sh`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
# example X.sh which calls Y.sh
./Y.sh
```

.

```
#!/bin/sh
# example Y.sh which needs to be called using sh -eux
echo $SHELLOPTS
```

.

```
#!/bin/sh -eux
# wrapper.sh which sets the options for all sub shells
export SHELLOPTS
./X.sh
```

Calling `X.sh` directly shows that `-eux` options are not set in `Y.sh`

```
[lsc@aphek]$ ./X.sh 
braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix
```

Calling it via `wrapper.sh` shows that the options have propagated to the subshells.

```
[lsc@aphek]$ ./wrapper.sh 
+ export SHELLOPTS
+ ./x.sh
+ ./y.sh
+ echo braceexpand:errexit:hashall:interactive-comments:nounset:posix:xtrace
braceexpand:errexit:hashall:interactive-comments:nounset:posix:xtrace
```

*Tested on GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release. YMMV.*

Comment: any idea for similar function in `/bin/sh` (on embedded system with only busybox's /bin/sh).

Comment: So, to do it in "one line": `bash -x -c 'export SHELLOPTS; ./X.sh'`

Comment: That's great! I found you can also use a subshell for quick debugging: `(export SHELLOPTS && bash -x ./X.sh)`.

Answer (score 1):

So i've got tool to debug shell scripts:

```
  #!/bin/sh

  # this tool allows to get full xtrace of any shell script execution
  # only argument is script name


  out=out.$1
  err=err.$1
  tmp=tmp.$1

  echo "export SHELLOPTS; sh $@ 1>> $out 2>> $err" > $tmp
  sh -eux $tmp &> /dev/null
  rm $tmp
```

Comment: it's better to add echo -n > $out ; echo -n > $err before sh