# linux: How to log all actions by the script tool(file) to save in a log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

linux: How to log all actions by the script tool(file) to save in a log file

Hi guys,

1)I hope to log what I wrote a script file, which include everything (e.g. some function may include
 remove a file, (rm -rf $file) that should contain which file to be deleted and the file name in the log file)
which means everything that script file performed.

2) can I output a readable format if 1) question be addressed?

thank you guys, hope to get you guys advices!

Comment: add `echo ...` before your command.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two alternatives:

- Use `echo` to log specific commands that you consider important to either `stdout` or `stderr`:

  ```
  echo "rm -rf $f"
  rm -rf "$f"
  ```

  For output to `stderr`:

  ```
  echo "rm -rf $f" >&2
  rm -rf "$f"
  ```

  Unfortunately this method can become very tedious to apply, since it has to be done manually. It also has issues when a command argument contains spaces; it requires a *lot* of work to quote the output in order to be able to reliably tell `"a" "b"` and `"a b"` apart.
- Run bash with the [`-x`/`xtrace` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) enabled. From the manual:

  > -x
  >
  > Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands,
  >   and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or
  >   associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are
  >   executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant
  >   value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

  To use you can either use `set -x` and `set +x` to enable/disable the option for specific parts of your script, or just enter it in the `bash` command line:

  ```
  bash -o xtrace script.sh
  ```

  To use `xtrace` recursively in subshells, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4325444/507519).

  One drawback of this alternative is that the output is *very* verbose and not as readable as explicit messages from `echo` - it is mostly suitable for debugging scripts, rather than logging under normal operation.

Comment: I would prioritize `set -x` as the primary option, and defer customized logging from inside the script as a distant second alternative. But +1 certainly.

Comment: @tripleee: IMHO it depends on what you want. If you are going to look at those messages often, `set -x` messages are quite tiresome to deal with. If you are just messing with a script for a few minutes, adding `echo` all over the place is a waste of time...