# How to make bash/shell "set -x" sticky across nested calls to shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to trace/debug a shell script that in turn includes nested invocations to other shell scripts.

My approach has been:

- set -x   (at the bash prompt)
- add  !/bin/bash -x to the main/entry point bash script

The second approach does end up showing the executions by the shell for the *main* script. But the nested scripts seem not to inherit that setting - either from the "set -x" on bash prompt or from the calling shell script.

Any way to achieve the inherited behavior - short of modifying each and every nested script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash recursive xtrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325444/bash-recursive-xtrace)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `SHELLOPTS` environment variable to make the "sub" shell use the same options. You just have to export it before any calls to subshells:

```
export SHELLOPTS
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was just typing too fast ;)