# How to enable debugging for all bash scripts at system-wide level

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I have a linux system that uses lots of bash scripts as the bootup scripts. I want to print all the bash statements that are being executed in order to debug some issue. How can I do that at system-wide level?

I had the following as `init` in my system :

```
$ls -la /init
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 20 Feb 10 04:46 /init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

I replaced `init` with a script like below :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
/lib/systemd/systemd
```

but no prints.

Comment: Shell options set with `set` apply to the current shell. They won’t affect child processes. You can test it with `sh -c 'set -x ; sh -c date'` (you won’t see anything like `+ date`).

Comment: Also see [Turn on xtrace with environment variable - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/536263/264812) and [How to make bash/shell "set -x" sticky across nested calls to shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25334800/4154375).

Comment: As explained in linked pages, put `export SHELLOPTS` in your new `init` before running `/lib/systemd/systemd`.  Be prepared for all hell to break loose if you have programs that `set -e` and/or `set -u` (and are coded appropriately) and call programs that don't set them (or expect them to be set).  Exporting `SHELLOPTS` causes most (`set`) Bash configurations to be inherited by subshells.  Also note that the trick won't work for Bash programs that have a `#! /bin/bash -p` shebang.  The  `-p` option (deliberately) much reduces the effect that environment variables have on the program.

Answer (score -1):

Download bash sources, change https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/flags.c#L88 to `echo_command_at_execute = 1`. `echo_command_at_execute`  might be reset somewhere later, in `reset_shell_flags()` and with `change_flag('x', 0)` - make `echo_command_at_execute` `const` and remove all assignments to it. Recompile and install. Create `sh -> bash` symlinks appriopriate for your system.

Note, that some scripts may parse stderr output of some shell programs. This modification may result in unstable system.

Answer (score -1):

I give an idea that do not confirm:

```sh
mv /bin/bash /bin/bashx
vi /bin/bash
/bin/bashx -x $@
```

Comment: This will not work. See the comment above from Biffen

Answer (score -1):

Copy `/bin/bash` to for example `/bin/bash2`, and similar with `sh`. Create an executable script:

```
#!/bin/bash2
/bin/bash2 -x "$@"
```

Repeat the process for `sh`. The paths have to be absolute.

Note, that for initrd you will have to regenerate it and include the copied executables and the scripts in the image. the copied executables in the image. Research your distribution specific ways about generating initrd.

Comment: So you said my answer will not work, then you give a same answer?

Comment: `set -x` followed by `/bin/bashx` is not `/bin/bashx -x`. `set -x` does not affect child processes (unless I think `export SHELLOPTS`)

Comment: I just gave a way to effect all the bash script. I know it's not perfect to work. And it needed to be debug.