# Zsh inherit xtrace option

Tags: zsh

Similar to this question: [bash recursive xtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325444/bash-recursive-xtrace), but for Zsh.

How can I make all the Zsh subshells inherit the xtrace option?

For example, if `script1.sh` is calling `./script2.sh` and I run `zsh -x script1.sh`, I want `script2.sh` to also have the xtrace mode enabled.

For Bash, the answer is to export the `SHELLOPTS` variable.

Is there a solution for Zsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of startup/shutdown files in Zsh (see `man zshall`): Zsh will always read (and execute) the file `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` at startup (if `ZDOTDIR` is unset, `HOME` is used instead). So you can put `set -x` in `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` and every Zsh script will run with xtrace mode enabled.

This is how I used it in a script:

```
env_dir="$(mktemp -d)"
echo "set -x" > "${env_dir}/.zshenv"
export ZDOTDIR="${env_dir}"
zsh "$@"
unset ZDOTDIR
rm -rf "${env_dir}"
```

In fact, this solution can be used for Bash as well, using the `BASH_ENV` variable, which points to a file that will, similarly, be executed when Bash starts.